# error is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException error creating bean with name "computerRestController"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

This error is about of between Controller and SpringBootApplication class

Actually, I didn't try anything, I just searched the internet. But there were no satisfactory answers. I wanted to use the Qualifier annotation. But my project had nothing to do with it.

Comment: Have you injected any Bean in `ComputerRestController`?

Comment: It's very probable that the answers on the internet will not fix your exact error, but they will point you to the answer. You could begin by reading the [other many questions about the exception here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=UnsatisfiedDependencyException).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.